# CSS for Label within Table for CGI Page

Tags: html, css

I need to create a CSS for label that is present inside a table tag. the css should change the color of the label.

I am using the below code to apply CSS.

```
#tableid > label
{

    color: #0047B2;
}
```

But the style sheet is not working.

Please provide an alternative way of applying style sheet to label tag within a table tag.

Comment: the use of `>` looks for `label` elements that are **immediate children** of the `#tableId` element. try removing the `>`.

Comment: the use of `>` looks for `label` elements that are **immediate children** of the `#tableId` element. try removing the `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just

```
#tableid label
{

    color: #0047B2;
}
```

It will work